# Is there a way to make each string from a list of strings into their own empty lists?

Tags: python, list, variables

here's what im trying to do:

oglist = ['a','b','c']

#add magical code here and print empty created lists

a = []

b = []

c = []

Answer (score 1):

Although, I **strongly discouraged** you to do it, you can create some variables dynamically with `globals()` or `locals()` (or `vars()`):

```
oglist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for og in oglist:
    globals()[og] = []
```

Test:

```
>>> a
[]

>>> b
[]

>>> c
[]
```

**Recommended approach**: It's preferable to use something like `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ogdict = defaultdict(list)
```

Test:

```
>>> ogdict['a']
[]

>>> ogdict['b']
[]

>>> ogdict['c']
[]
```

As you can see with `defaultdict`, you don't need to have the key before in your dict. The entry is created dynamically.